# Core Plot: plotArea only updated after viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I use the release-2.0 branch of Core Plot from Swift. My app needs to draw things on top of the graph. I use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to detect changes in the bounds, like after a rotation to landscape. I position my subviews with `plotSpace.plotAreaViewPointForDoublePrecisionPlotPoint` but in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` this returns the old position. After some digging I discovered that in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` `hostedGraph.bounds` are updated correctly but `plotArea.bounds` not yet. The following code shows that `plotArea.bounds` are updated after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` gets called.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    println("from viewDidLayoutSubviews")
    showBounds()
    let time : dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0)
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        println("after viewDidLayoutSubviews")
        self.showBounds()
    })
}

func showBounds() {
    println(chartView.hostedGraph.bounds)
    println(chartView.hostedGraph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.bounds)
}

// Output:
// from viewDidLayoutSubviews
// (0.0, 0.0, 667.0, 343.0)
// (0.0, 0.0, 361.0, 616.0)
// after viewDidLayoutSubviews
// (0.0, 0.0, 667.0, 343.0)
// (0.0, 0.0, 653.0, 324.0)
```

I don't know if this is expected behavior or not.
How can I get the correct `plotArea.bounds` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Answer (score 0):

`-viewDidLayoutSubviews` is tied to updates to the view hierarchy. I don't think there are any guarantees about when the Core Animation layers within the hosting view are laid out after the views are laid out.

You can always call `-layoutIfNeeded` on the graph to make sure its layout is up-to-date before reading the bounds of any of its sublayers.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, calling `layoutIfNeeded` will update the `plotArea.bounds` correctly.